# Best way to handle dynamic keyword with JSON?

Tags: c#, json, security, dynamic

I have the following code:

```
using (System.IO.StreamReader r = new System.IO.StreamReader(path))
        {
            var json = r.ReadToEnd();
            dynamic jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);

            foreach (var item in jsonData)
            {
                var value = item.Student.code;
                if (storedValue == Studentcode)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
```

I would like a work around for using dynamic as my security has scanned this code and does not think it is secure.

Comment: Security scan software generally gives you an explanation of what the security vulnerability might be.  If it doesn't hold, file an exception.  If you want to keep it dynamic, consider deserializing it into a `Dictionary<string, object>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead using dynamic when you have to deserialize a JSON I would suggest using either :

1- If you know that the json only content its the student object :

```
Student jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Student>(json);
```

2- If you don't know if the only content in your JSON is your object student itself but you know that it's not nested inside another object you can deserialize the string as a whole and then select which object you want to retrieve :

```
var parsedObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
var studentObject= parsedObject["Student"].ToString();
var responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Student>(studentObject);
```

Edit: If it's nested you can just iterate throught the objects like you would with an array example:

```
parsedObject["NestedInThisObject"]["Student"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the structure of the JSON, you could create a DTO and deserialize into that type instead of the dynamic type, then use the DTO for the same operations you use against the dynamic type.